# Ошибка при обновлении данных в Power BI веб версии из Bigquery

Tags: powerbi, bigquery

После добавления набора данных с подключением к Bigquery в веб версию появляется проблема.[image: Ошибка набора данных]

В десктоп версии подключение проходит без проблем. Авторизация в веб версии также проходит без проблем, но в итоге всё равно появляется данная ошибка при обновлении страницы, набора данных или спустя некотороое время (менее часа).
Переавторизация через инкогнито, другого браузера и даже другого аккаунта с аналогичными правами не дает результата.
В отчетах, где несколько источников данных такая же проблема только с подключением к Bigquery.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Подскажите, решилась ли ваша проблема?
Если да, то как?